# Rotate a 3D cube in a Python Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a cube(s) within a 3D array using analytical equation. Here is the code:

```
A = np.zeros((150, 150, 150))   #the array containing the cube
r = 15   #cube's edge length, randomly
c = (39, 36, 119)   #cube's center, randomly
for x in range(c[0] - r, c[0] + ):
  for y in range(c[1] - r, c[1] + r):
     for z in range(c[2] - r, c[2] + r):
       deb = r - max(abs(c[0] - x), abs(c[1] - y), abs(c[2] - z))   #cube's equation
       if deb >= 0: 
       A[x, y, z] = 1
```

This code produces a cube with exactly the same direction as the coordinates:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBBhP.png)
Then, I used scipy.ndimage.rotate method to rotate the cube at an arbitrary angle:

```
A = scipy.ndimage.rotate(A, np.random.randint(0, 90), reshape=False, axes=(0, 1))
```

that give the result:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrbuX.png)
The problem is here. If I keep the parameter `reshape=False`, I can preserve the array A's dimension, but sometimes the cube is cropped after rotation like this:
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Eqb.png)
On the other hand, if I choose `reshape=True`, the cube is successfully rotated without any crop or division, but the shape of array A is also changed.
My question is, is there any possible solution to solve these two problems?

I tried different methods of rotation. This one (`scipiy.ndimage.rotate`) seems to be elegant and useful for my further tasks so I want to stick with this one.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To make this question more accessible, it would help to give the rotation angle at which the error occurs. My initial guess is that this is connected to the [mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) settings of scipy's rotate function. Also (more out of interest) - what plotting library are you using?

Comment: @ChristianKarcher thanks for your comment. I'm using my company's software, which is used to analyze the biomedical image. Btw you can use other 3D visualization software to observe the cubes because it's basically just a 3D array.